# update multipleimage using dropzone and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dropzone

i have an annonces table which contains multipleimages field, i want to use a dropzone which can update annonces images, in console it displays

```
> ["888.jpg"]
> ["zzzz.jpg"]
```

as two array, so I want to send two images to controller for update.

**details.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('annonces/filesUpdate')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}                            
                         </form>
```

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function filesUpdate(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $Annonce=Annonce::find($id);
        
        $data = array();
         if($request->hasFile('images'))
         {
            foreach($request->file('images') as $file)
            {
                $path = $request->images->store('annonces');
                $Annonce->images = $path;
                array_push($data,$path);
            }
         }
        $Annonce->images = json_encode($data);
        $Annonce->save();
        return Redirect::to("annonces")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```